# Reshaping an array from 1D to ND in C

Tags: c, arrays, list-manipulation

I am having a lot of trouble trying to implement this on my own, so if anyone can point to, or describe an algorithm I'd be much obliged.

**The problem statement**

Given one dimensional flattened pointer `int* i` which would look something like this `{1,2,3,4}`, and given a list of dimensions in form of a list `{2,2}` reshape the 1D array to conform with specified dimensions. Overall after the procedure the array should look like `{{1,2},{3,4}}`.

I am basically asking if anyone knows the algorithm that is used in numpy.reshape.

Comment: What stops you from looking into NumPy's source code?

Comment: The fact that I did not know that it's opensource (and still don't).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A n-dimensional array in [c](/questions/tagged/c) is nothing more than syntactic sugar for computing the offset inside a simple array, they look the same in memory (one contiguous block). Therefore, there's really no point in "reshaping" it, as this little sample demonstrates:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int data[] = {1,2,3,4};

int main(void)
{
    int *i = data;

    for (int n = 0; n < 4; ++n)
    {
        printf("i[%d] = %d\n", n, i[n]);
    }

    int (*j)[2] = (void *)i;

    for (int n1 = 0; n1 < 2; ++n1)
    {
        for (int n2 = 0; n2 < 2; ++n2)
        {
            printf("j[%d][%d] = %d\n", n1, n2, j[n1][n2]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output:

> i[0] = 1
>   i[1] = 2
>   i[2] = 3
>   i[3] = 4
>   j[0][0] = 1
>   j[0][1] = 2
>   j[1][0] = 3
>   j[1][1] = 4

Comment: Yeah, this is simple iterative solution however there is no bound on the number of dimensions, to reshape it to 999 dimensions I'd need exactly 999 for loops, doesn't sound very good.

Comment: @VahagnTumanyan the loop "demonstrates" that access through a `*int[2]` pointer works just as expected. There's really no "reshaping" happening, just aliasing through a pointer of different type.

Comment: @VahagnTumanyan Even though 999 dimensions has two bottom elements, the overall size becomes (2^999)*sizeof(element). Are you kidding?

Answer (score 0):

NumPy doesn't need an algorithm, because it stores data contiguously regardless of the shape.  The "shape" property is the only difference between the input and the output of `reshape()`.  The algorithms come into play when later accessing the array, such as when printing it.  Then you need to follow the shape to know how many elements go in each row or other dimension.